# No Articles for countable and definable words

Tags: articles, determiners

[**Source**](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/energy/efficiency/housing/home-improvements/keeping-the-heat-in/basement-insulation/15639)

Have a contractor apply ( ) water proofing material from ( ) grade level down.

Why do you think "material" and "level" are without an article?

Comment: _Material_ is not countable. _The_ could appear with _level_, but _grade level_ is the baseline and therefore would become the default expression and drop the article. Rather like the phrase _top dead center_ in internal combustion engine design; I've never heard or seen it as _the top dead center_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was just struggling with this. Is it safe to say that indicators of location or direction can take the definite or no article, as in _We live at sea level_ or _We drove from (the) East to (the) West?_ (Of course, I know that it's never safe to say _anything_ where the articles are concerned...)

Comment: I wouldn't guarantee that descriptive phrasing, but certainly those examples are the same phenomenon with the same result. _Sea level_ is a fixed baseline phrase, like _standard temperature and pressure_.

Comment: @JohnLawler, material is not countable? Can you elaborate? Then what's with "a material" and "materials" in dictionaries?

Comment: That means 'a kind of material'; it's the sort of thing that happens when you force a mass noun into a count noun frame. You get a type interpretation of the mass noun (like _seven inks_, meaning 'seven kinds/colors of ink') fairly often. _Material_ is similar in meaning to _mass_, in fact.

Comment: @JoeKim: Many nouns, such as *material*, can be either countable or uncountable. Typically there is a slight difference in meaning. "A material" means a kind of matter -- for example, cotton is "a material" -- whereas "material" just means matter -- for example, a long dress uses more "material" than a miniskirt. (That said, I think that uncountable *material* is more often used in figurative senses: for example, a college course might cover "a lot of material", or a journalist might "gather material" for a story.)

Comment: The [**dictionary entry**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/material_1) for _material_ tells the reader:"[uncountable, countable]" and provides clear examples of both usages.

Comment: @ruakh, Thanks. It's easy to understand your explanation. Can you give an explanation on grade level with no article as well?

Comment: This could be related: [should there be a definite article before “eye level”? (a quote from Salinger)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14974/should-there-be-a-definite-article-before-eye-level-a-quote-from-salinger)

Answer (score 1):

> Why do you think "material" and "level" are without an article?

Nouns used as types don't take articles.  Articles make a noun talk about a specific instance of something, but when we are talking about the type, we aren't doing this anymore.

> What kind of socks should I bring?  Bring red ones.  (Red is a type of sock.  I don't care where they come from as long as they are red.  If you have some, great.  If you have to buy some from a store, whatever.)
>
> WHICH socks should I bring?  Bring the red ones. (There exists a number of red socks, that you should know about, and I want you to bring those red socks.)

So:

> Have a contractor apply ( ) water proofing material from ( ) grade level down.

We want to contractor to apply something that is a type of material that is waterproofing, but we aren't telling him to get any instance of existing material - there may be a pile of that material there, but we don't know that.

Since articles make nouns talk about specific instances of something, when we use a noun to talk about a concept of something (e.g. "X in general"), or in the abstract, we don't use the article either.

> Socks feel really good on your feet.  (Socks as a concept.)

The speaker/writer is considering "grade level" as a concept.  If a person had actually measured the grade level, it may become "concrete-ized" and they may then say *the grade level.*

Comment: I remember how I was surprised by the lack of an article before "eye level" (I added a comment below the question).

Comment: Socks is a terrible example, because a) it only exists in the plural like trousers and glasses (of course you can wear a monocle instead, or one sock only), and therefore doesn't need the article where the singular would require *a* or *the*. The plural is the easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

*"water proofing material"* seems to be an **indirect object** to "apply" and it's an **adverbial objective**.

*"grade level down"* looks like the **adverbial objective** of the **adverbial prepositional phrase** that it forms in combination with *"from"* and *"down"*.

A verbose version would be "downwards from the grade level to the ..."

Compare that with the apparently related ["go home vs go to home"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=go+to+home) and  [usage of go to vs go](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158141/usage-of-go-to-vs-go), because I\m not really sure, just trying to point at additional information, even if I might have it mixed up.